# Error message when writing and applying a function. X must be numeric but it already is

Tags: r, function, dplyr, cut

I'm trying to create a custom-made function based on this one: [How to create a variable with the quantiles of another one in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258254/how-to-create-a-variable-with-the-quantiles-of-another-one-in-r)

I write this code and it works

```
base_conjunta <- base_conjunta %>% 
    mutate(centils100_total_canvi = cut(total_canvi, unique(quantile(total_canvi, seq(0, 1, 0.01))), labels = FALSE))
```

Then I write a function based on this code

```
centils100 <-function(data,x) {
  x <- enquo(x)
data %>% 
    mutate(x = cut(x, unique(x, seq(0, 1, 0.01))), labels = FALSE,.names = "centils100_{col}")
}
```

I run it:

```
base_conjunta <- centils100(base_conjunta, "total_canvi")
```

But I obtain:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `across(...)`.
Caused by error in `cut.default()`:
! 'x' must be numeric
Backtrace:
  1. global centils101(base_conjunta, "total_canvi")
 13. base::cut.default(x, unique(x, seq(0, 1, 0.01)))
 14. base::stop("'x' must be numeric")
```

The 'x' (the total_canvi variable) is already numeric because when I do it with a normal mutate this error message does not appear.

Why does this happen? I don't know what I'm doing wrong when writing the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.names` ca be used in `across`.  If we meant `across`, the code can be modified to

```
centils100 <-function(data,x) {  
data %>% 
    mutate(across(all_of(x), ~ cut(.x, 
    breaks = unique(c(.x, seq(0, 1, 0.01))),
    labels = FALSE), .names = "centils100_{.col}"))
}
```

-testing

```
> centils100(mtcars, "mpg") |> head(2)
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb centils100_mpg
Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4            116
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4            116
> centils100(mtcars, c("mpg", "qsec")) |> head(2)
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb centils100_mpg centils100_qsec
Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4            116             106
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4            116             110
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. But when I run it, it says this: Error in `ensym()`:
! Can't convert to a symbol.
Backtrace:
 1. global centils100(base_conjunta, c("poblacio", "total_canvi"))
 5. rlang::abort(message = message)

Comment: @FrancoBattiato Your example showed a single column passing into the function

Comment: @FrancoBattiato As you are passing a vector of column names, just remove the `ensym` and it should work as in the update

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I've tried but it says: "Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `centils100_total_canvi`.
Caused by error in `cut.default()`:
! 'breaks' are not unique
Backtrace:
  1. global centils100(...)
 12. base::cut.default(...)
 13. base::stop("'breaks' are not unique")". Thanks

Comment: @FrancoBattiato your code had some typos.  I didn't check the `unique` step you have used.  Is it `unique(c(.x, seq(0, 1, 0.01)))`